# How can I get the count of sequential events pairs from a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID  EVENT   DATE
1   1       142
1   5       167
1   3       245
2   1       54
2   5       87
3   3       165
3   2       178
```

And I would like to generate something like this:

```
EVENT_1  EVENT_2  COUNT
1        5        2
5        3        1
3        2        1
```

The idea is how many items (ID) go from one event to the next one. Don't care about previous states, I just want to consider the next state from the current state (e.g.: for ID 1, I don't want to count a transition from 1 to 3 because first, it goes to event 5 and then to 3). 
The date format is the number of days from a specific date (sort of like SAS format).

Is there a clean way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
(df.groupby([df['EVENT'].rename('EVENT_1'), 
             df.groupby('ID')['EVENT'].shift(-1).rename('EVENT_2')])['ID']
   .count()).rename('COUNT').reset_index().astype(int)
```

Output:

```
|    |   EVENT_1 |   EVENT_2 |   COUNT |
|---:|----------:|----------:|--------:|
|  0 |         1 |         5 |       2 |
|  1 |         3 |         2 |       1 |
|  2 |         5 |         3 |       1 |
```

***Details:*** Groupby on 'EVENT' and shifted 'EVENT' within each ID, then count.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html). We'll also use [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to tidy up the final output:

```
(pd.concat([f.groupby([f['EVENT'], f['EVENT'].shift(-1).astype('Int64')]).size()
           for _, f in df.groupby('ID')])
 .groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum()
 .rename_axis(['EVENT_1', 'EVENT_2']).reset_index(name='COUNT'))
```

[out]

```
   EVENT_1  EVENT_2  COUNT
0        1        5      2
1        3        2      1
2        5        3      1
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the shift function, I wasn't aware of that. Unfortunately, this doesn't consider the IDs. The count should be in terms of how many IDs transition from each event to the next one. Maybe I wasn't clear about the IDs, they are the objects that are transitioning from event to event. The solution should not include event_1 = 3 and event_2 = 1

Comment: ahhh, I see, my apologies. I'll updated my answer, with the addition of the `groupby('ID')` - also necessary to add [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) as well now